# "+" behaving strangely in my functions

Tags: javascript, operators

i'm making a mathematics app.
there, i want to be able to generate mathematic tasks with randomized operations.

```
var generator = {

    operations: [
        "+",
        "-",
        "*",
        "/"
    ],

    randomOperation: function(amount) {
        if (amount == 2) {
            return this.operations[Math.round(Math.random())];
        }
        if (amount == 4) {
            return this.operations[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
        }
    },

    addOperand: function(operand, maxSize, minSize) {
        var op = operand;
        console.log('op ' + op);
        if (operand == 2||4) {
            console.log('getting random operand');
            op = this.randomOperation(operand);
        }
        var number = this.randomNumber(maxSize, minSize);
        console.log('number ' + number);

        this.tasks.push({
            value: number,
            operation: op
        });
        console.log('added ' + op + ' ' + number);
    }
    // other stuff
}
```

so i want to be able to call the method with varying arguments:
'+', if i definitely want it to be a +
'-', if i want a -
and so on
if i pass a number (2 or 4), it is supposed to generate randomly out of 2 (+-) or 4 (+-*/)

but something really strange happens...

the console output is:

```
op +
getting random operand
number 2
added undefined 2
```

why is '+' considered 2||4 ?
it is clearly coming in as '+', but then somehow... passed to randomOperation(), which, of course, returns nothing.

thanks

PS: is there a way to paste code on here without the pain of manually correcting all the indentations? it's really annoying :(

Comment: math.random() only returns in the range `[0,1)`. with the floor operation, you'd only ever get `0`...

Comment: the way to paste code with proper indentation is to have it properly indented to start with, paste it, select it, then press the `{}` button to make it "code"

Comment: p.s. re entering code: the `{}` button, or Ctrl-K, in the post editor will indent the selected chunk of code.

Comment: Marc B but its the floor of math.random * 4. that should be between 0 and 3, shouldn't it?

Comment: @user3787706 no, it'll be between 0 and 3 inclusive

Comment: @Alnitak yeah but that's what i want! (random out of 4-index array)

Comment: you changed your comment - it said 0 and 4 originally ;-)

Comment: yes you were too fast :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `operand == 2 || 4` is parsed as `(operand == 2) || 4`.

It will be `true` if `operand == 2`, or `4` otherwise.

Both possible results are "truthy", and therefore the `if` branch is always taken, regardless of the value of `operand`

If instead you want the branch to be taken only if the operand is 2, or 4, you need:

```
(operand == 2 || operand == 4)
```

Comment: Good explanation of the broken branch and how it is "short-circuiting" as an unintended effect.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
if (operand == 2||4) {
```

doesn't mean "if operand == 2, or operand == 4" -- it means "if operand == 2, then `true`, otherwise `4`.

You want to say:

```
if ((operand == 2) || (operand == 4)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not how you can check to see if a value is one or the other. What that code is doing is

```
if ( (operand==2) || 4 )
```

So id operand is 2 it is true, else it returns 4 which is truthy value. So basically it will always be true.

The check needs to be

```
if( operand == 2|| operand == 4)
```

or you can use modulus

```
if (operand %2 === 0)
```

or indexOf

```
if ([2,4].indexOf(operand)>-1)
```